# Azure Function (Service Bus): Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Just before I get to the question, I must confess I'm very new to Azure Functions thus not truly understanding "the over-all".

A bit about the Environment we have an "API" which inserts "some" data then pushes a model to a Service Bus Queue.

We then have an Azure Function which triggers on Service Bus message received, admittedly this works perfect unless left for 30-60 seconds, then an error is thrown.

This is all done locally (VS17)... There is no logic, all I do is debug and view the contents of the message.

Ideally I'd like to know why I'm receiving this error to begin with, I assume behind the scenes the Azure Function needs to stay in state of active connection.

[image]

I'd really appreciate some guidance, or advice on missing parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that you are using web job console app for some future job which triggered by service bus message. In the end of your screenshot I see that you you didn't write in App.config for this app connection string to AzureWebJobsStorage. Is this a full screen of all errors, from beginning?

Comment: It might be useful if you could simply copy and paste the test from the output into the question

Comment: S.Divnych,  pm_2 the core method, is a stripped back only one line... The Console, admittedly stripped out some sensitive info. Give me 30mins, and I'll get the report.

Comment: Could you still add the code of your function to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the hosting plan of your Azure function. You would have chosen either Consumption plan or App Service plan at the time of creation and this cannot be modified.

The hosting plan can be potential reason behind your function getting timed out.
The default timeout for functions on a Consumption plan is 5 minutes. The value can be increased for the Function App up to a maximum of 10 minutes by changing the property functionTimeout in the host.json project file.

In the dedicated App Service plan, your function apps run on dedicated VMs on Basic, Standard, Premium, and Isolated SKUs, which is the same as other App Service apps. Dedicated VMs are allocated to your function app, which means the functions host can be always running.